# How to check DropDownlist is null or not in mvc using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to check  @Html.DropDownList("Countries","--select--") is null or not using Jquery

Comment: a SELECT Element cannot be null! Your title is also different!  What is your real question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
$('#mySelectList > option').length;
```